# Validation for form on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where I have many textboxes which are getting validated through *Required field validator*, But there is a *captcha* control also which is not getting validated. However I can validate it through javascript.

Here alert gets displayed when I click on 'OK' of alert message box. 
But I want this message to be displayed on button click simultaneously with other validations.

Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide jsFiddle.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried using `.on('submit', function(e){...});` instead? Then inside that, you will need to loop through all of your input(s) using some sort of loop or if statement. That will make all of them fire one after another. As you have it now, only the captcha is getting fired.

Comment: I want to validate captcha on button click, you can see my javascript code.. It validates but gives the message after the other validation..Is there any way out, so that I can display the message after when I fill the whole form except the captcha box ??

Comment: @Andrei Cristian Prodan,  Is there any way out, so that I can display the message after when I fill the whole form except the captcha box ?? –

Comment: @Naddem Khan  Can you provide your html?

Comment: @Bernardo, how to attach the file ?, I have it on my local

Comment: @Bernardao Please see [link]  <captcha:CaptchaControl ID="CaptchaControl1" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Extreme" CaptchaFontWarping="Medium" Display="Dynamic" autocomplete="off" ></captcha:CaptchaControl>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                                                ErrorMessage="Please enter First Name" ControlToValidate="txtFName"
  Display="None" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: @Bernardao: Also see     <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" class="button-form" ValidationGroup="VG" OnClick="btnSend_Click" CausesValidation="true" />

Comment: use "edit" button on question.

Comment: @bernardao, I have edited and provided you the html and js. Thanks..

Comment: @MikeWu: Please find the js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nadeem/jCY7b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to display the "Please enter captcha text." as part of the `ValidationSummary` control.

To do this, you just need to let the server-side know the captcha text. Do this:

1. Add another textbox, but keep it hidden with `display:none`:

   `<asp:textbox id="txtCaptcha" runat="server" style="display:none;">`
2. Modify your Javascript to copy the captcha value into the `txtCaptcha` textbox:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#' +'<%=btnSend.ClientID %>').on('click', function (e) {
              var captcha = $("input[name$=CaptchaControl1]").val();
              $('#' + '<%=txtCaptcha.ClientID %>').val(captcha);
          })
      });
   </script>
   ```
3. Create a `RequiredValidator` for `txtCaptcha` textbox:

   `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorForCaptcha" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter captcha text." ControlToValidate="txtCaptcha" Display="None" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`

Comment: Simcha\:When I fill all d data,including d captcha field also.Then I when I click on submit button,first time it shows me alert box to fill d captcha text and then it gets submitted.

Comment: Hii, Can anyone help with this ?
When I fill all d data,including d captcha field also.Then I when I click on submit button,first time it shows me alert box to fill d captcha text and then it gets submitted.

Comment: Simcha: Even when I fill the captcha code, It still shows me the pop up to fill the captcha text, can u please help ?

Comment: Please find the link http://jsfiddle.net/nadeem/jCY7b/. Please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: As per your javascript code, its not copying the captcha value in the textbox, that is why it's giving me the validation  message even after I fill that.

Comment: Identify the client side ID of the captcha. That's what you need to find.

Comment: Is this the Client side ID of the captcha ? "ContentPlaceHolder1$CaptchaControl1"

Comment: or ('<%= CaptchaControl1.ClientID %>') is this the client ID

Comment: If you run the application, riht-click, view source, find the captcha input field. It will have an `ID` attribute.

Comment: In .aspx I am giving the ID, but on the source view it's no generating the ID attibute ? y so ?? Now how i will get the ID of Captcha control ?

Comment: ID of server controls are generated by ASP.NET. Whats the value? If you run the application, riht-click, view source, find the captcha `<input>` field. It will have an ID attribute. What is that ID?

Comment: Im sry but the captcha control is not generating ID on run time, please see the source code for your ref. 
   <!-- Captcha code start -->
                                            <div><span style='margin:5px;float:left;'><img src="CaptchaImage.aspx?guid=0073e8ad-ba3f-4900-98d8-be8f1876058e" border='0' width=180 height=50></span><span style='margin:5px;float:left;'>Enter the code shown:<br><input name=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CaptchaControl1 type=text size=5 maxlength=5 value=''></span><br clear='all'></div>

                                            <!-- Captcha code end -->

Comment: What does `alert('<%=txtCaptcha.ClientID %>')` return?

Comment: Its returning me ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCaptcha as alert. on click

Comment: but the value of captcha is not getting copied in the textbox.

Comment: sir: Please help me with this, getting tough for me now. Sorry  for disturbing.

Comment: Replace the line with this `var captcha = $("input[name$=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CaptchaControl1]").val();`